# How to use RaiseError Function twice in same email send to log error in same DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder, triggered-send, send-email

We are using RaiseError function twice in same email send and also logging error message in DE.
But it only inserts entry for second scenario how ever email code fails both scenarios but we want to keep record of all raised error message for each email send. Is it feasible or that's how ampscript work?
We are sending email using UI sends. Send Log DE is without any Primary Key and have all nullable fields.

```
Logic :-

If (value1 is not empty) Then
SET @Var = "Value1"
Else
SET @errormessage = "Value1 is empty"
InsertDE("SendLogDE","SendJobID",@jobid,"errorText",@errormessage )
RaiseError (@errormessage, true, 1)
ENDIF
------Some email related code---
If (value2 is not empty) Then
SET @Var = "Value2"
Else
SET @errormessage = "Value2 is empty"
InsertDE("SendLogDE","SendJobID",@jobid,"errorText",@errormessage )
RaiseError (@errormessage, true, 1)
ENDIF
```

Outcome:-
If value1 and Value 2 both are empty still SendlogDE have records as below
SendJobID errorText
11092    Value2 is empty

Expected outcome :-

SendJobID errorText
11092     Value1 is empty
11092     Value2 is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, once the code block hits a valid raiseError, execution stops there.
Based on the raiseError option used, it will either skip the current send and pick next subscriber or block the entire send

RaiseError - https://ampscript.guide/raiseerror/

Meaning, you will never get two error insertion associated with two raiseError() call in a single send.
So, your expected outcome will never happen.

Regarding your output order, I am a bit doubtfull because there is no execution order mentioned for your two raiseError() call.

I replicated using below code with two adjecent raiseError() and its always inserting the first one.

```
%%[
SET @condition1 = TRUE
IF (@condition1) THEN
    InsertDE('ErrorLog', 'uuid', _subscriberkey, 'errorMessage', 'Error 1 ')
    RaiseError("error1", true, 1)
ENDIF

/*some extra codes*/

SET @condition2 = TRUE
IF (@condition2) THEN
    InsertDE('ErrorLog', 'uuid', _subscriberkey, 'errorMessage', 'error2')
    RaiseError("error2", true, 1)
ENDIF
]%%
```

So, if you want both error to be available in the errorLog DE and at the same time if you can afford the delay in raiseError call after the error is logged, replace the raiseError() call with a specific flag variable and call raiseError once both the insertion conditions are checked and executed.

```
%%[
SET @isError = FALSE
SET @condition1 = TRUE
IF (@condition1) THEN
    InsertDE('ErrorLog', 'uuid', _subscriberkey, 'errorMessage', 'Error 1 ')
    SET @isError = TRUE
ENDIF

/*some extra codes*/

SET @condition2 = TRUE
IF (@condition2) THEN
    InsertDE('ErrorLog', 'uuid', _subscriberkey, 'errorMessage', 'error2')
    SET @isError = TRUE
ENDIF
IF (@isError) THEN
    RaiseError("error", true, 1)
ENDIF
]%%
```